# Find predictors in lm object R

Tags: r, object, lm

I have a linear model in R

```
 x <- lm(dist ~ poly(speed, degree=2), data = cars)
```

and want to find out,

a) which variables of cars are used as predictors in the model. Here: "speed"

b) how to access them in the model object. Here:  4  4  7  7  8  9 10 ...

model.frame contains the already transformed terms and does not help. The lm object contains the data, as expand.model.frame(x, ~ speed) does work. But where is it?

Any hints?

Comment: You could start by typing `x`  then typing `str(x)`

Comment: hmm, well, i did... but had no luck!

Comment: did you try out x$model$speed ?

Comment: Yes: 
> x$model$speed
NULL. This returns the model.frame.

Comment: I provided an answer for the first qustion. What do you mean exactly by the second question?

Comment: this should work: `eval(x$call$data)[,all.vars(formula(x)[[3]])]`

Comment: Indeed it does! Thanks! Why not answer and get the points instead of comment?

Comment: Why the downvote? Be at least fair and comment!

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of the variables, you can use `all.vars`:

```
all.vars(formula(x))
[1] "dist"  "speed"
```

To get only the predictors:

```
formula(x)[[3]]
poly(speed, degree = 2)
all.vars(formula(x)[[3]]) # Use the third element of the formula
[1] "speed"
```

Comment: This is quite promising, thanks. Now I know the used variables. How can I access the data in the lm object, say cars[, "speed"]?

Comment: Use `str(x)` to see the content of you model object. You can then see that the data are stored within the 'model' slot inside your `lm` object and you can retrieve it like this : `x$model`

Comment: If you would complete your answer with e.g. timfabers solution, I could accept it as totally solved...

Answer (score 1):

`x$coefficients` will give you the predicted influence of each variable on the outcome

I made a simmilar model here:

```
x<-lm(cyl~ mpg, mtcars)
(Intercept)         mpg 
11.260683   -0.252515
```

if you added in additional you would have additional coefficients:

```
 x<-lm(cyl~ disp + mpg, mtcars)
 x$coefficients
(Intercept)         disp          mpg 
 5.917863266  0.009197743 -0.092206375
```

And you can get the whole lowdown by using `summary`

```
    Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.3002 -0.6138  0.1776  0.5486  1.1406 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  5.917863   1.255293   4.714 5.61e-05 ***
disp         0.009198   0.002011   4.574 8.27e-05 ***
mpg         -0.092206   0.041352  -2.230   0.0337 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.7364 on 29 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8409,    Adjusted R-squared:   0.83 
F-statistic: 76.66 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 2.647e-12
```

the model data set(just the first few here):

```
head(x$model)
                  cyl disp  mpg
Mazda RX4           6  160 21.0
Mazda RX4 Wag       6  160 21.0
Datsun 710          4  108 22.8
Hornet 4 Drive      6  258 21.4
Hornet Sportabout   8  360 18.7
Valiant             6  225 18.1
```

and you can access the parts of the model with typical object class queries:

```
x$model$cyl
[1] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 6 8 8 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 4 8 8 8 8 4 4 4 8 6 8 4
```

And the predicted result for each observation based on your model(just the first few):

```
head(x$fitted.values)
        Mazda RX4     Mazda RX4 Wag        Datsun 710    Hornet 4 Drive Hornet Sportabout           Valiant 
         5.453168          5.453168          4.808914          6.317664          7.504791          6.318420
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this wasn't what I was looking for. I have predictors in some kind of transformation in the model formula and wanted to know which ones were needed.

Comment: Sorry bout that. I sometimes struggle to understand what people are actually asking. I do not use language the way most programmers do...

Comment: :-) no problem!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to finding the predictors in an lm object is this:

```
# the model
x <- lm(dist ~ poly(speed, degree=2), data = cars)

# finding names of predictors in the model
colnames(model.matrix(x$model)) #this includes the intercept in the names of predictors

colnames(model.matrix(x$model))[-1] #this excludes the intercept from the names of predictors
```

For the sake of completeness, I wanted to add this too. `Getting the names of responses (or outcomes) in an lm object`

```
colnames(model.frame(x$model)[, 1])
```